# I have a Problem with error log AWS Workspace, What could be happening or how can I solve it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace, amazon-workspaces

Good evening.

Hoping that someone can help me with these records that I am rescuing from AWS Workspace:

1° [ERR] Failed to make a request to: https://d1cbg795sa4g1u.cloudfront.net/prod/iad/d-90676a9d4d/en_US/wsassets.json. Message: HttpClient - 4xx Network Error

2° File 'debug_data.json' not found

What could be happening or how can I solve it?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you much but you can turn on verbose log output by starting the workspace application from a console and adding the -l4 flag. Shame the documentation is so lacking.